# Workaround OSError with os.listdir

Tags: python, macos

I have a directory with 90K files in it. This is such a preposterously huge number of files that bash functions like `ls` fail. So of course, does `os.listdir()` from my python (Mac Python, version 2.5) script; it fails with `OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory: '.'`

People will say "Don't put that many files in a single directory! Are you crazy?" -- but I like to pretend that I live in the future, a brilliant, glowing place, where I have gigabytes of memory at my disposal, and don't need to worry too much about where exactly my files go, as long as there's rust left on my spinning platters.

So, is there a good workaround for this `os.listdir()` problem? I've considered just shelling out to `find`, but that's a bit gross, and unfortunately `find` is recursive, with no supported maxdepth option on Mac OS X 10.6.

Here's what the os.listdir via shelling out to find looks like, roughly:

```
def ls(directory): 
    import os
    files = os.popen4('find %s' % directory)[1].read().rstrip().split('\n')
    files.remove(directory)
    return files # probably want to remove dir prefix from everything in here too
```

**Update:** `os.listdir()` succeeds in python 2.6.

Comment: What is the error that you get? I routinely use `os.listdir` to get directory listings with 50-100k files in them. `os.listdir` is also the fastest choice, since it doesn't `stat` every file in the directory.

Comment: @Seth, I get OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory: '.'

Comment: Approximately how many files are in this directory?

Comment: @Garrett gets an A+ for reading comprehension.  D:

Comment: Well, think about it. "I have a directory with 90K files in it," is ambiguous. It could mean, "The contents of the directory totals 90K," or "The directory has N number of 90K files."  So, I'm curious as to whether the problems lies with total file size or the total number of files.

Comment: I don't think four 90k files would qualify as a "preposterously huge number of files".  :P

Comment: Which python (mac ports, apple, which version?), which Mac OS X? You must be hitting a bug in some old python version. I just listed a directory with 65000 files in it, and Python's only using 8MB real + 23MB VM.

Comment: @Garett 90,000 files of various sizes.

Comment: @Seth I'm using Apple's python 2.5.4 on OS X 10.6.

Comment: +1 for eloquently putting it :) `People will say "Don't put that many files in a single directory! Are you crazy?" -- but I like to pretend that I live in the future, a brilliant, glowing place, where I have gigabytes of memory at my disposal, and don't need to worry too much about where exactly my files go, as long as there's rust left on my spinning platters.`

Comment: Ironically, here in 2013, most mac laptops have SSDs so they don't have to worry about spinning platters, much less rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def ls(directory): 
    """full-featured solution, via wrapping find"""
    import os
    files = os.popen4('find %s' % directory)[1].read().rstrip().split('\n')
    files.remove(directory)
    n = len(directory)
    if directory[-1] != os.path.sep:
        n += 1
    files = [f[n:] for f in files] # remove dir prefix
    return [f for f in files if os.path.sep not in f] # remove files in sub-directories
```

Comment: Yes, it would work, but won't help with the performance issue on 90k files.

Comment: I'm just looking for something that would work -- don't care about performance. A performant solution that doesn't work isn't a solution.

Answer (score 8):

You're hitting a historical artifact in Python: `os.listdir` should return an iterator, not an array.  I think this function predates iterators--it's odd that no `os.xlistdir` has been added.

This has more effects than just memory usage on huge directories.  Even on a directory with just a few thousand files, you're going to have to wait for the entire directory scan to complete, and you have to read the *entire* directory, even if the first entry is the one you were looking for.

This is a pretty glaring lack in Python: there appears to be *no* binding to the low-level `opendir`/`readdir`/`fdopendir` APIs, so it seems like it's not even possible to implement this yourself without writing a native module.  This is one of those cases where it's such a huge, gaping hole in the standard library that I doubt myself and suspect I'm just not seeing it--there are low-level `open`, `stat`, etc. bindings, and this is in the same category.

Comment: Always nice to see mysterious downvotes.  I guess it's the "daring to criticize Python" penalty.

Comment: `ImportError: No module named criticize`

Comment: That would imply `ImportError: No module named improvement`.

Comment: Or you're getting downvoted for not answering the "is there a good workaround?" question.

Comment: @Russell: My answer to that was pretty straightforward: as there's no `opendir` binding, short of writing a native module there's no workaround for this issue.  (Of course, I'm aware that many people will downvote things without bothering to read them.)

Comment: I fiddled with an xlistdir() a while back, and it worked for my limited purposes. Today I would go with a ctypes solution. +1 for adding it to standard python.

Comment: @Terrel, ctypes would be platform-specific, depending on the exact layout of `dirent`.  I'd strongly recommend against that.

Comment: ugg..does this really not exist in the python standard library?

Answer (score 4):

You could try going one level deeper and directly call opendir() and readdir() using ctypes.

Comment: Desperate, but if `listdir` and `ls` fail it's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: This is tempting, but the problem is that `readdir` returns data as a `struct direct`, and the layout of that is platform-specific.  I think the only *reliable* way to implement this is with a native module.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same IOError on Apple Python 2.5.5 on 10.6 when listing a big directory. It works just fine in Python2.6.

```
Python 2.5.5 (r255:77872, Sep 21 2010, 09:52:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> x = os.listdir('.')
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory: '.'
```

This seems to be a bug in Python2.5. See "[os.listdir randomly fails on occasions when it shouldn't](http://bugs.python.org/issue3115)" and "[Sloppy error checking in listdir() for Posix](http://bugs.python.org/issue1608818)".