# Pandas read_json too many open files error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I keep getting a 'Too many open files' error when doing something like this:

```
# read file names
file_names = []
for file_name in os.listdir(path):
    if '.json' not in file_name: continue
    file_names.append(file_name)

# process file names...

# iter files
for file_name in file_names:

    # load file into DF
    file_path = path + '/' + file_name
    df = pandas.read_json(file_path)

    # process the data, etc...
    # not real var names, just for illustration purposes...

    json_arr_1 = ...
    json_arr_2 = ...

    # save DF1 to new file
    df_1 = pandas.DataFrame(data=json_arr_1)
    file_name2 = os.getcwd() + '/db/' + folder_name + '/' + file_name
    df_1.to_json(file_name2, orient='records')

    # save DF2 to new file
    df_2 = pandas.DataFrame(data=json_arr_2)
    file_name3 = os.getcwd() + '/db/other/' + folder_name + '/' + file_name
    df_2.to_json(file_name3, orient='records')
```

The DF documentation doesn't mention having to handle open or closed files and I don't think listdir keeps pointers to open files (should just return a list of strings).

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: At which point do you get the error? Have some files been already processed then? Perhaps `file_names` include some paths with wildcards?

Comment: Crashes after the second file is processed. Only .json files in that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a system issue, and not pandas issue.

You might need to increase the number of open files in the system.

How to increase number:
https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/

The following Q&A:
[IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280612/ioerror-errno-24-too-many-open-files)
discuss about ulimit and the limit of open files

This Q&A discuss about number of open files in Linux:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux

Comment: But the number of file names could vary so this could happen for n files *(1 read + 2 saves). Should the limit be 3 or should the limit be n*3? But if I don't know n ahead of time, I can't set a limit.

Comment: How many files are being opened in your program? The system limit should be high enough for a "normal" operation

Comment: That's my question... Am I opening more than 3? I think I'm just opening 3, 1 to read json, 2 to write json. So total of 3. But it would be 3+ if pandas didn't release the files on each loop...

Comment: I see the following line in your code: "for file_name in os.listdir(path)" - how many ".json" files do you have in directory named "path"?

Comment: about 6000 files. But that just lists the file names... no? Not actually opens them. The crash happens on the second for loop though, not while reading from the directory.

Comment: I'm not sure that you are correct... - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4099039/5088142 -  
You're hitting a historical artifact in Python: os.listdir should return an iterator, not an array. I think this function predates iterators--it's odd that no os.xlistdir has been added.